# Is it possible to share files from documentum to Microsoft teams group?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to explore Microsoft Team, so that i can integrate documentum and Microsoft teams.So want some idea is there any support present in Microsoft team, so that I can download file from documentum and directly upload to Microsoft team groups chats. I am able to do documentum part download file but how i can upload that file to Mic. Team app.I want some guidance from where to refer this thing or this kind of thing is possible in this or not . If possible so please  refer some material so that i can go through that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you wish to just share the files from doumentum to specific team(group) present in Microsoft Teams? Files are store on SharePoint for each team, I believe you can use connectors to sync the files. Could you please share more specific scenario on how users are going to use it?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT my scenario is like if we have team created in Microsoft team and we want to send some document from documentum repository to Microsoft team app conversation(in chats). One more thing i want to access all the conversation thing so is there any api present to access that?

Comment: You can get all the channel messages using [/messages Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_get_message).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT yes i got that but how can i uplaod file to conversation from documentum to team.

Comment: Currently you cannot upload directly from documentum. I am checking with team if it would be supported in future.

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT , for now we can to upload our file to sharepoint and with help of connectors, we can sync in conservation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the channel messages using [/messages Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_get_message).

Uploading files form Documentum is currently not supported in Microsoft Teams. But if Documentum is an [Office Cloud Storage Partner](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cloud-storage-partner-program) we may do it in the future.

For now, you can use the connectors to upload your files to SharePoint.

Note: added answer from comments for visiblity.